# Php parse to javascript variable or array

Tags: php, javascript

I have this php script

```
<?php
                    include ("db.php");
                    $result = mysql_query("SELECT fbuid from fbusers");
                    while($array = mysql_fetch_array ($result)){                            
                    print("alert ($array[0]);");
                                                                   }
 ?>
```

I want to store the returned values in a javascript variable or array so I can check if a fb user it's already registered in my app.
Could somebody tell me how could I store the `mysql_fetch_array` to javascript?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-and-escape-newlines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can always create a div use your php code that has an unique id and concatenate all your $arrays in the div, then just use something like the following in javascript to get your values

```
var x=document.getElementById("your_div_id");
alert(x.innerHTML);
```